# How to display files where the name starts with an 'a' and has a 'c' as third letter?

Tags: linux, shell

Display files in home directory starting with 'a' and third letter as 'c'.
This is what I have tried:

```
ls | grep '^a.c$'
```

But this is printing start with 'a' and ending with 'c'.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Unix

Comment: You probably don't want the $ at the end of your expression, as you don't care what comes after the 'c' - you do need the ^ at the start.  You could also use the ls globbing wildcard: `ls a?c*` You could also look at `find -name 'a?c*'`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To meet your requirement, you can use

```
ls | grep -x a.c*
```

The `-x` option for `grep` means whole line match.

As for your current approach, `$` stands for "end of line", so files ending with `c` will be printed.

Comment: or with globbing: `ls a?c*`